# Rails "NOT NULL constraint failed: table.column"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a accounts table with not null constraint on its name and number column.
I also have this piece of code for "accounts" controller in create Action:

```
def create
    account_number = rand.to_s[2..9]
    @account = Account.new(user_id: current_user.id, name: 'hello', number: account_number)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @account.save
            format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: "Account was successfully created.\n Your account number is: #{account_number}" }
```

and my "Account" model is very simple:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :number
  attr_accessor :amount
end
```

But when I go to /accounts/new and submit, it gives me this error:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts.name

But why? because I have hard codded the "name" attribute with "hello" in the constructor, so why it is not filling "name" column with "hello"?

Comment: can you please post the table schema

Comment: my last migration was:
class AddAccountsNotNullConstraint < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column :accounts, :name, :number, :null => false
  end
end

which also ruined the the type of "name" from string to decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `attr_accessor` calls from `Account`.  They are likely overriding the built-in methods that are generated from your schema, which will cause any number of problems.

Did you create and run a migration to add these attributes to the `accounts` table?

Comment: yes I did, you were right. I just removed attr_accessors and the problem is solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `:user_id`, `:name`, `:number` and `:amount` fields you don't need to add `attr_accessor` for them.

Also, you can add Model-level validation on `:name` to avoid the `database-level` error.

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: But does not it results to an error any way? I mean what is the exact advantage of this avoidance?

Comment: This will return you the error from model itself. It will not go to the database until the validation are satisfied

Comment: This way it will not break the not null constraint at db level but will properly give you the validation message saying "Name can't be blank" and will rerender the edit page again if you are rendering it